# Interpolating multivariate polynomials from their partial derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation

Let $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a multivariate polynomial over a ground field $K$. For a multi-index $\alpha=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ we denote the partial derivative $\frac{\partial^{a_1+\dots+a_n}P}{\partial x_1^{a_1}\dots\partial x_n^{a_n}}$ by $\frac{\partial^\alpha P}{\partial\mathbf{x}^\alpha}$.

Given points $\mathbf{p}_1,\dots,\mathbf{p}_m\in K^n$ and  multi-indices $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$ such that the pairs $(\alpha_i,\mathbf{p}_i)$ $(1\leq i\leq m)$ are pairwise distinct,  I am interested in polynomials $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ over $K$ that satisfy 
$$
\frac{\partial^{\alpha_i} P}{\partial\mathbf{x}^{\alpha_i}}(\mathbf{p}_i)=v_i\quad (1\leq i\leq m)
$$
where $v_1,\dots,v_m\in K$ are chosen arbitrarily.

*Question: What is the minimum degree $d=d(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m)$ with the property that for any choice of the values $v_1,\dots,v_m$ there exists a polynomial $P=P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of degree at most $d$ that satisfies these equalities?*

Notice that each $\frac{\partial^{\alpha_i} P}{\partial\mathbf{x}^{\alpha_i}}(\mathbf{p}_i)=v_i$ defines a hyperplane in the polynomial space since it is linear with respect to the coefficients of $P$. The intersection of these hyperplanes is the affine subspace of desired polynomials in the vector space of polynomials of $n$ variables of total degree at most $d$. Therefore, if these hyperplanes are transversal the answer is given by the smallest $d$ for which $\binom{d+n}{n}\geq m$.

Special univariate cases: If $n=1$, $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$ are all zero and elements $p_1,\dots,p_m\in K$ are distinct, we are in the classical case of Lagrange interpolation; the aforementioned hyperplanes are transversal by a simple application of the Vandermonde determinant. The transversality could also be checked easily when $n=1$, $p_1=\dots=p_m$ and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$ are distinct non-negative integers (the Taylor expansion provides a formula for $P$). In both cases the smallest $d$ is $m-1$, i.e. the first degree that satisfies $\binom{d+1}{1}\geq m$.

**Added:** I am looking for the smallest $d$ that works. For instance, when $n=1$ it is not hard to see that large values of $d$ work: Suppose $p_1,\dots,p_m$ are distinct elements of $K$. Consider the linear map
$$
P(x)\mapsto\left(\frac{{\rm{d}}^a P}{{\rm{d}}x^a}(p_i)\right)_{0\leq a<l,\, 1\leq i\leq m}
$$
from the space of polynomials of degree $<d$ in $K[x]$ to $K^{lm}$. The kernel is given by the multiples of 
$\prod_{i=1}^m(x-p_i)^l$ which is of dimension $d-lm$ if $d\geq lm$. So the map is onto for $d$ large enough and any arbitrary set of identities 
$$\frac{{\rm{d}}^{a_i} P}{{\rm{d}}x^{a_i}}(p_i)=v_i\quad (a_i<l)$$ 
can be realized in that case.

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939190294I